# Query on Address allocation in C

Tags: c, memory-address

Can u pls help me undertand this basic item:

i have two varibale i and J , my query is i have initialized "I" and later on "J", but first address was allocated to J instead of "I".

Can u help me understand why ?

address for I and 4 bits higher than J

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("%d",sizeof(int));
    printf("enter the number to multiply wuth 1 through 10:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("size of I:%d\n",sizeof(i));
    for(int j=0;j<=10;j++){
    
        printf("%d\n",i*j);
        printf("Address of j:%d\n",&j);
    }
    printf("%d",&i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is free to arrange the variables in memory as it finds fit.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages, so please don't use the [tag:c++] tag when asking a question about C.

Comment: The address for `I` will likely be 4 *bytes* (not bits) higher than `J`, but that is an implementation based on the compiler standards and the size of `int` types on your system. As for why? As others stated the underpinnings of how a compiler chooses to generate your assembly are out of your control, but the answer is quite simple really. In many `C` compilers, local variables are created on the stack. The stack grows from high addresses to low addresses, so naturally the first `int` allocated by the compiler will be at a higher address on the stack.

Comment: If you remove the line where you print `&j` and analyze the assembler code of your program, you may discover that `j` is not stored in memory at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compilers use their own algorithms to decide how to allocate memory among variables, based on many factors such as alignment and cache line usage.  There is no guarantee that they will be arranged in memory in the same order as their declaration, nor any particular reason to expect this to be the case.  (And unless you take the address of the variable, it may be optimized into a register which doesn't occupy memory at all.)

Answer (score 2):

It is totally compiler-dependent. As all these variables are stored in Stack, we can not decide which address is provided to which variable.
Try to run the same code multiple times and you may find the address of I is allotted before j.

Thanks

Comment: It's unlikely to change between runs.

Comment: Running the code several times won't change the relative addresses, these are fixed in compile time.

Comment: The relative position will not change between runs, but the actual addresses will likely change if ASLR and PIC are implemented.